# Animate root view controller transition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I want to animate the transition between one root view controller and another. I could hypothetically perform a segue to the other view controller instead of switch roots, but if possible I would like to maintain the root view controller transition. Here's what I have to do this without animation.

```
let initialViewController = UIStoryboard.initialViewController(for: .main)
self.view.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

How would I do this with, say, an animation where the first controller slides up and away and reveals the second one?

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be:
1. Set 2nd ViewController as root view controller.
2. Add 1st ViewController's view to 2nd Controller.
3. Remove 1st Controller's view with animation.

Code:

```
class View2Controller: UIViewController {

    var viewToAnimate:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        if let view1Controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View1Controller") {
            self.addChildViewController(view1Controller)
            self.view.addSubview(view1Controller.view)
            self.viewToAnimate = view1Controller.view
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.5) {
            let frame = self.view.frame
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.viewToAnimate?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -frame.height, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                if finished {
                    self.viewToAnimate?.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.viewToAnimate?.frame = self.view.bounds
    }
}
```

Effect:
[image]

Source code on Github:
[SlideUp Demo](https://github.com/chenyun122/CYDemos/tree/master/SlideUp)

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't ever change your root view controller.

The way I deal with this, therefore, is that my root view controller is not my root view controller. Instead, I have a "secret" root view controller which is the *real* root view controller. It effectively does nothing; its view contains no interface. Its only job is to act as the parent to every other "root" view controller; it is a custom parent view controller (container view controller), and it always has one child view controller.

A moment's thought will show that now the problem is solved, because the business of replacing a child view controller and its view with another child view controller and its view, while transitioning with animation between the views, is straightforward and well-documented.

Comment: How does this play out in terms of launching into a certain view controller? For example, if a user is logged in, show the home page, and if they’re not show the login page.

Comment: That sounds like a _completely_ different question. Don't "leech" or "comment-churn"; ask it as a new question!